# What is this thing between the engines on the F-14 Tomcat?

Tags: feature-identification, f-14

On the F-14 as you can see from a picture there is some exhaust like thing in between engines. What is this?

[image]

Comment: Related [drawings](http://www.anft.net/f-14/f14-detail-beavertail.htm).

Answer (score 19):

This is the line for [dumping fuel](https://books.google.de/books?id=J-8cAgAAQBAJ&pg=SA1-PA52&lpg=SA1-PA52&dq=F-14%20fuel%20dump%20line&source=bl&ots=7WP8SFkTeO&sig=6uCoMgffd4mbTfbfbbDTFZXXTqg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMIyfbN-ImdyAIVRMUUCh3Zhwj5#v=onepage&q=F-14%20fuel%20dump%20line&f=false) in an emergency. If the F-14 needs to land quickly but is too heavy for landing, fuel can be pumped overboard through this pipe. To the left of it is an antenna, and the rod below the fuselage is the arrestor hook.

The [Australian F-111s](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/why-does-the-f-111-sometimes-squirt-a-giant-fire-plume-behind-it-not-afterburn?s=1%7C1.8557) use the same arrangement to great effect during flight displays.

From the F-14 [Walk-Around Photo Index Page](http://www.aircraftresourcecenter.com/awa01/101-200/awa169-tomcat/00.shtm):

[image]

> Back end of the "beaver tail".  The red hole is the fuel dump point.
>   The beige item is the rear ALQ-126 antenna, paired to the ones on the
>   wing glove area.  This antenna, like the forward ones, was introduced
>   with block 110 F-14As and all subsequent aircraft.  Also visible is
>   the hook portion of the arresting hook.

Comment: Cool. From its appearance and location I would have guessed it was an APU exhaust. Do fighters even *have* an APU?

Comment: @TomMcW: Yes, most modern ones do. See [here for a related question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9325/if-the-epu-emergency-power-unit-on-a-modern-fighter-jet-fails-will-the-aircra)

Answer (score 6):

The only thing I can add here, is that the two square holes on the underside next to the tail hook, are for the chaff and flares.

Comment: Hello there and welcome to Aviation.SE. We're not like other forums; the answer box is only for answer. This post should be a comment because it does not answers the question. That said, I think it does add interesting information so I think we can have an exception here. Just remember, next time use the comment feature to comment (-:

Comment: From the picture holes look right above the hook. I wonder how they avoid hitting the hook.